# Amend existing jQuery ajax function to retrieve latest inserted value from json and mark as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here's the workflow of my form:

Display form with input and select elements >> all of the select elements have a button to add new data via a modal window that performs a database insert via ajax and closes the modal window >> on modal close, I fire the refreshData() function which pulls in the new data from json into the select elements of the form.

All of the above is working great, but how do I mark the correct option (last added via modal window) in the refreshSelect() function below? For example: I add a new supplier to my database via modal window, it inserts correctly to the DB, but how do I mark that new supplier as selected after modal window close?

Here's a sample of the json data I'm working with:

```
{"suppliers":{"1":"Amazon","2":"Lenovo"},"manufacturers":{"1":"Apple","2":"Lenovo"},"categories":{"2":"Tablet"},"status":{"1":"Ready to Deploy","2":"Deployed","3":"Damaged"}}
```

jQuery function that will pull data from json via ajax and refresh the select elements on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initial load
  refreshData();
});

function refreshData(newId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/collection.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers, newId);
      refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers, newId);
      refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status, newId);
      refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories);
      refreshSelect('inputManufacturerModel', data.manufacturers, newId); //modal window select
    }
  });
}

function refreshSelect(name, data, newId) {
  // Select by id
  let $elem = $('#' + name);
  // Get current value
  let oldValue = $elem.val();
  // Get "template" value with value 0, which is the first element
  let emptyOption = $elem.children('option').first();
  // Empty the element and add the option. We are back to initial state
  $elem.html(emptyOption);
  // Append elements retrieved from backend
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  });
  if(newId){
      $elem.val(newId);
  }else{
      $elem.val(oldValue);
  }
}
```

Function that will insert new values to the database via ajax from the modal window (Very basic):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.modal-submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit action

        $(".backend-error").html(''); //clear out previous error messages
        $('input').removeClass('input-error'); //clear error border class

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var type = $(this).find('input[name="type"]').val();

        switch(type){
            case "supplier":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'supplier']) }}';
                var modalName = '#supplierModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputSupplierNew';
                break;
            case "manufacturer":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'manufacturer']) }}';
                var modalName = '#manufacturerModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputManufacturerNew';
                break;
            case "model":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'model']) }}';
                var modalName = '#modelModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputModelNew';
                break;
            case "status":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'status']) }}';
                var modalName = '#statusModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputStatusNew';
                break;
            case "category":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'category']) }}';
                var modalName = '#categoryModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputCategoryNew';
                break;
        }

        $.ajax({
           url:url,
           method:'POST',
           data:data,
           success:function(response){
                refreshData(newId = response.id); // set newId to the id of the newly inserted item
                $(modalName).modal('hide'); //hide modal
                $(modalInput).val(''); //clear input value
           },
           error:function(e){
                //console.log(error.responseJSON.error)
                //console.warn(error.responseJSON.error);
                $.each(e.responseJSON.error, function (i, error) {
                    $(modalInput).addClass('input-error');
                    $(modalName + ' .backend-error').html(error[0]); //return error from backend
                });
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: Revised code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the required `new value` to be set to select box from your `ajax POST`'s success handler to your `refreshData()` call and ultimately to your `refreshSelect()` function as follows:

Save Data Call:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
console.log(data);

/*TODO*/
var newSupplierId = <logic to get ID/Name of newly added supplier>;

var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addAttribute', ['type' => 'supplier']) }}';

$.ajax({
   url:url,
   method:'POST',
   data:data,
   success:function(response){
      if(response.success){
          refreshData(newSupplierId); //passing newSupplierId  to refreshData function
          $('#supplierModal').modal('hide');
          $('#inputSupplierNew').val('');
          console.log(response);
      }else{
          alert('There was an error inserting data. Please try again.')
      }
   },
   error:function(error){
      console.log(error)
   }
});
```

Other modified code:

```
function refreshData(newSupplierId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/collection.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers, newSupplierId);
      refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers);
      refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status);
      refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories);
      refreshSelect('inputManufacturerModel', data.manufacturers); //modal window select
    }
  });
}

function refreshSelect(name, data, newSupplierId) {
  // Select by id
  let $elem = $('#' + name);
  // Get current value
  let oldValue = $elem.val();
  // Get "template" value with value 0, which is the first element
  let emptyOption = $elem.children('option').first();
  // Empty the element and add the option. We are back to initial state
  $elem.html(emptyOption);
  // Append elements retrieved from backend
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  });
  if(newSupplierId) // check whether newSupplierId is null or not
  {
      //if newSupplierId is not null means select newly added supplier
      $elem.val(newSupplierId);
  }
  else{
      // Restore selection
      $elem.val(oldValue);
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. You spelling it out for me helped get my mind on track. Works great!

Comment: hey thats gr8 buddy...!

Comment: I edited my question with my revised code. Having a new problem, would you mind taking a look? It works great when only updating one select on the page, but when there are multiple selects on the page using the same function, the newId variable is resetting the value of all select elements in the form.

Comment: @DerekM.- In such case you may pass `var type = $(this).find('input[name="type"]').val();` to `refreshData(newId,type);` and then `refreshSelect` accordingly. You will have to add another `switch case` statement in `refreshSelect` to target exact select box as per passed `type`